# Console outputting state which is not yet updated in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, console.log

First of all, I have no idea if this problem is related to Chrome console, Redux or JavaScript objects.

I have the following function in my React + Redux app:

```
function InputReducer(state = [{ }], action) {
    console.log('input-reducer.js', 'state', state[0], JSON.stringify(state[0]));
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'STORE_INPUT_VALUE':
            let newState = {};
            newState = state[0];
            _.set(newState, action.storePointer, action.value);
            console.log('input-reducer.js', 'newState', newState, JSON.stringify(newState)); 
            return [newState];
        break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I know the state should not be replaced, but updated instead. Don't mind about it now, this is in the middle of the process.

This works, but what I don't understand is that when I see the logs, when updating the state, the first log returns exactly the same object as the newState. This should not be possible, since as far as I know, the function which updates the state should not be executed at a time when logging happens.

What makes this even more weird is that when I stringify the object, it returns correct, expected values.

If I modify the function to return some nonsense state, like this:

```
function InputReducer(state = [{ a: 0 }], action) {
    console.log('input-reducer.js', 'state', state[0], JSON.stringify(state[0]));
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'STORE_INPUT_VALUE':
            let k = state[0].a + 1
            let newState = {a: k};
            console.log('input-reducer.js', 'newState', newState, JSON.stringify(newState)); 
            return [newState];
        break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

...the logs show the objects correctly... or at least they seem as I would expect them to be.

So what is this behaviour related to and what am I missing here?

Comment: What's the value of `action.storePointer` and `action.value`? It's possible you're either not actually updating any values or the path to the value is invalid.

Comment: @MikeC Well, the paths are login.home.user for example and the values are whatever comes from the input. But I don't think this is the problem. The values are updating correctly, its just that IMO the first logging should not show the updated value, but the old value.

Comment: When you're comparing them in the console, are you looking at the object reference or the JSON? The object reference will be identical but the JSON should be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newState = state[0];` gives you the reference to the 1st element in the array.

`_.set(newState, action.storePointer, action.value);` Your `newState` is modified, therefore `state[0]` is modified directly.